# TFS 2015: Order values for <STATE> field

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-workitem, workitem

We have a customized TFS Process (template) based on the newest Agile Process and everything is working beautifully, except for the order of the valid-values within the *State* field (see screenshot).

I've searched high and low and cannot seem to find out any tips on how these values are ordered. I would like to order them in their proper-flow, the same as how the Kanban board orders the Process's set *State* values.

Any ideas? I've looked within the .xml files for the WIT definitions and the Process flow but nothing is standing out. Thanks for any info!

[Image: Customized State values, not exactly order how we'd wish..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0rjh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No such setting to sort order for State field. It arranges in alphabetical order.

Comment: You can try to submit your ideas at website https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015.